# render partial in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, renderpartial

In my application I have an button as below.

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#askNetworkFormModal" class="hidden-xs btn btn-primary mb-10" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
   <span class=""><b>
     Ask
   </b></span>
</button>
```

Here data-target is modal call **askNetworkFormModal** which is in _askthenetwork.html.erb

I rendered it within application.html.erb as below

```
<%= render partial: 'layouts/askthenetwork' %>
```

I just want to render this only for the page which include my button. How can I do this.

Comment: What about putting the button in a partial and also render the `askthenetwork` button in the same partial?

Comment: What errors or trouble are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had resolve this by changing code as below.

```
<% if controller_name =="home" && action_name == "feed"%>
    <%= render partial: 'layouts/askthenetwork' %>
<% end %>
```